# How can I solve for $r$ in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with the following:

> Given:
>   $$ 
> r^2(x^2-2x+1+y^2)+r(2x^2-2x+2y^2)+x^2+y^2-1=0 \tag 1
> $$
>   Solve for $r$:
>   $$
> r=\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{(1-x)^2+y^2} \tag 2
> $$

I'm confused because in $(1)$ $r$ is squared, but not in $(2)$.

Attempt:
$$
r^2(x^2-2x+1+y^2)+2r(x^2-x+y^2)+x^2+y^2-1=0\\
r[r(x^2-2x+1+y^2)+2(x^2-x+y^2)]+x^2+y^2-1=0\\
$$
What is the next step?

Comment: Equation (1) happens to factor. One root is $r=-1$. Perhaps this is discarded due to constraints on $r$ (eg, it may be considered a non-negative length).

Comment: Any thoughts about the three answers you have received, Donsert?

Answer (score 3):

Let's write $a=x^2-2x+1+y^2$, $b=2x^2-2x+2y^2$, and $c=x^2+y^2-1$, so the equation is $ar^2+br+c=0$. Note that $b=a+c$, so the equation is $$0=ar^2+(a+c)r+c=(ar^2+ar)+(cr+c)=ar(r+1)+c(r+1)=(ar+c)(r+1)$$ So $r+1=0$ and $r=-1$, or else $ar+c=0$ and $$r=-{c\over a}={1-x^2-y^2\over(1-x)^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If a polynomial with respect to $r$ looks bad 
$$
r^2(x^2-2x+1+y^2)+r(2x^2-2x+2y^2)+x^2+y^2-1=0,
$$
you can try rewriting it as polynomial with respect to other variables, say $x$
$$
x^2 (r^2 + 2r + 1) + x (-2r^2 -2r) + (r^2-1) + y^2(r^2 + 2r + 1) = 0.
$$
Now you can see the pattern -- squares of $r+1$ are present
$$
x^2 (r + 1)^2 - 2xr(r+1) + (r+1)(r-1) + y^2(r + 1)^2 = 0.
$$
Thus one solution is 
$$
\boxed{r=-1}
$$
and you can divide by $r+1$
$$
x^2 (r + 1) - 2xr + (r-1) + y^2(r + 1) = 0.
$$
The latter is a linear equation with respect to $r$, thus easily solvable
$$
(x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2)r + (y^2 + x^2 - 1) = 0,
$$
$$
\boxed{
r = \frac{1 - x^2 - y^2}{x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2}.
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By the quadratic formula we get
$$r_{1,2}=
-\frac{2x^2-2x+2y^2}{2(x^2-2x+1+y^2)}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{2x^2-2x+2y^2}{2(x^2-2x+1+y^2)}\right)^2-\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2-2x+1+y^2}}$$